# How to access await function variable outside function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement an `await` function which local variable I am trying to access outside the function. However, I'm not getting the value which is defined inside function.

```
async CreateProduceRateAsset(data, callback) {
    // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
    try {
        var TimeStamp = new Date();
        var TxId = '';
        var blockNumber = '';
        const result = await contract.submitTransaction('CreateProduceRateAsset', args);

        await network.addBlockListener('block-listener', (err, block) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            TimeStamp = block.data.data[0].payload.header.channel_header.timestamp;
            var Tx_id = block.data.data[0].payload.header.channel_header.tx_id;
            var BlockNO = block.header.number;

            console.log('TxId', Tx_id)
            console.log('blockNumber', BlockNO)

            TxId = Tx_id
            blockNumber = BlockNO

            return TimeStamp, Tx_id, BlockNO
        });

        console.log('Timestamp', TimeStamp)
        console.log('TxId 123', TxId)
        console.log('blockNumber 123', blockNumber)

        response.data = result
        return callback(response);
    } catch (error) {
        response.httpstatus = 404;
        response.message = `Failed to get MVP Price ${error.message} `;
        return callback(response);
    }
};
```

In the above code, I want to access `Tx_id`, `Timestamp` and `BlockNO`. For that, I am assigning a local variable to a global variable, however, I'm still getting the value of those as blank.

Could someone help me to get those values?

Comment: Where did you assign it to global variable? And where did you use it?

Comment: Please show how you call that function in your code.

Comment: And reduce your code to be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @Daniel_Knights I have reduce the code as requested

Comment: Wait, you're not supposed to use both async and callback function. Only one is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand `network.addBlockListener` is a callback-based API and not return a promise so you cant `await` it, I guessed that you use https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Network.html

Here is your code with my comments

```
async CreateProduceRateAsset(data, callback) {
  // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
  try {
      var TimeStamp = new Date();
      var TxId = '';
      var blockNumber = '';
      const result = await contract.submitTransaction('CreateProduceRateAsset', args);
      // --> this api is callback based and wont not return a promise so you cant await it 
     await network.addBlockListener('block-listener', (err, block) => {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return;
          }
          TimeStamp = block.data.data[0].payload.header.channel_header.timestamp;
          // --> becasue you are inside a function these vars are not the same as the one ouside the call back , becasue they are scoped to this function 
          var Tx_id = block.data.data[0].payload.header.channel_header.tx_id;
          var BlockNO = block.header.number;
          console.log('###########TxId#####################', Tx_id)
          console.log('###########blockNumber#####################', BlockNO)
          TxId = Tx_id
          blockNumber = BlockNO
// --> you can only return one value in js, also this reurn is useless since you dont call this callback
// --> better way to get these vars outside the callback is to pass them to your own callbak like this `callback(response,TimeStamp, Tx_id, BlockNO)`
          return TimeStamp, Tx_id, BlockNO
      });
      console.log('*************** Timestamp:: **********************', TimeStamp)
      console.log('###########TxId#####################123', TxId)
      console.log('###########blockNumber#####################123', blockNumber)

      response.data = result
      return callback(response);
  } catch (error) {
      // if(error) throw error;
      // response.error = error;
      response.httpstatus = 404;
      response.message = `Failed to get MVP Price ${error.message} `;
      return callback(response);
  }

};
```

if you need to use async/await with `network.addBlockListener` you can use `utils.promisify` to convert it to promise-based API but I don't recommend it since this an event listener

Comment: While the "can't be awaited" is probably correct, why are you **still** awaiting it?

Comment: I didn't fix the code I just commented on it to clarify the problem with the code snippet

Comment: Thanks@salamaashoush I look into your code and my code also I found the issue with await function I need to call  await  network.addBlockListener('block-listener', (err, block) => { }  before other await function const result = await contract.submitTransaction('CreateProduceRateAsset', args);

Comment: @AbhijeetSamanta It's not correct. You can't do that in large code. It messes your code up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your return into a variable like this:

```
var data = await network.addBlockListener('block-listener', (err, block) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    TimeStamp = block.data.data[0].payload.header.channel_header.timestamp;
    var Tx_id = block.data.data[0].payload.header.channel_header.tx_id;
    var BlockNO = block.header.number;

    console.log('###########TxId#####################', Tx_id)
    console.log('###########blockNumber#####################', BlockNO)

    TxId = Tx_id
    blockNumber = BlockNO
    return {TimeStamp, Tx_id, BlockNO};
});
    
console.log('*************** Timestamp:: **********************', data.TimeStamp)
console.log('###########TxId#####################123', data.Tx_id)
console.log('###########blockNumber#####################123', data.BlockNO)
```

Now you can store all your values into `data` and put them into the desired variables.

Comment: hi@Ali Esmailpor its come undefined value *************** Timestamp:: ********************** undefined
###########TxId#####################123 undefined
###########blockNumber#####################123 undefined

Comment: Please just console data and show what it is.

Comment: ["The comma operator (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), `return TimeStamp, Tx_id, BlockNO` would only return `BlockNO`

Comment: Yes, I correct that to this:
return {TimeStamp, Tx_id, BlockNO};